# In es6 I need my promise to return true or false when done

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

In es6 I need my promise to return true or false when done

This is my attempt but it returns a promise and I need it to be true or false

```
return this.isUserAuthenticated()
   .then(() => this.checkIfTeacherProfileExists());
```

The return part needs to be true or false.

**This is what one of the returns looks like:**

```
  isUserAuthenticated = (): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  
        this.authService.checkIfLoggedIn().then((isAuthUser: boolean) => { 
            resolve(true); 
        });
    }); 
  }
```

Comment: *"but it returns a promise and I need it to be true or false"* Seems like you haven't understood the fundamentals of promises. Maybe have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise and https://www.promisejs.org/ .

Comment: Also related: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196)

Comment: People shouldn't use Promises until they understand the underlying problem being addressed.

Comment: I need to do 2 async calls and when they are done they then need to return true or false. Hows best to do this?

Comment: @AngularM The others here have tried to say it but haven't gone into detail. If you are performing an asynchronous action, it is not possible to return `true` or `false` because your function will return _before_ the asynchronous action has completed. You can return a Promise for true/false, then the function that calls `isUserAuthenticated` needs to expect a promise to be the result, not a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return is a promise holding `true` or `false`. So all you have to do is to chain another `.then()` which will hold the boolean.

```
return this.isUserAuthenticated()
   .then(() => this.checkIfTeacherProfileExists())
   .then(v => console.log(v)); // true or false
```

Regarding your comment, see @FelixKling's comment - you can't do that, that's not how promises work.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work. I need the return to be true or false.

Comment: I need something like this: 

       return this.isUserAuthenticated()
         .then(() => this.checkIfTeacherProfileExists())
         .then(this.canContinueToRoute);

Comment: I need to return this.canContinueToRoute as the two functions update that boolean